# Does entity relation also get loaded into memory when entity gets fetched in CoreData?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm working on an app that allows the user to create a little comic from a photo. I've implemented `CoreData` so the user can save and reedit their comic. I've created two entities: `ComicInfo` and `ComicDetails` which have a relationship with one another (I did it this way from reading the Ray Wenderlich tutorial). So when the user saves a comic, I make a new `ComicInfo` `NSManagedObject`, store the name and thumbnail in it, then I create a `ComicDetails` `NSManagedObject`, store various attributes in that, and I store the `ComicDetails` in the `ComicInfo` and save.

I've created a UITableView that displays the thumbnails and names from all the ComicInfo objects to allow the user to select one so they can edit the comic.

What I'm wondering is, why did I separate this into two entities instead of just doing them in one? I'm assuming that when I load all of the `ComicInfos` from `CoreData`, that the `ComicDetails` will also be loaded into memory, or am I wrong about that? In a perfect world, I'd like it so only the `ComicInfos` are loaded when the `UITableView` is launched, then when the user selects one of the rows, the associated `ComicDetails` will then be loaded into memory. Is that not what's happening here?

Comment: *"I store the ComicDetails in the ComicInfo..."* Do you mean you have a relationship? If so, could you edit the question to describe it? And if not, could you describe what you mean?

Comment: @TomHarrington - Yes, there is a relationship between the two that I'm denoting in the xcdatamodeld file. When I'm creating the ComicInfo and ComicDetails, I'm also doing comicInfo.details = comicDetails. Just realized I'm not setting the comicDetails.info though (dunno if it makes a difference).

Comment: You don't need to set the inverse relationship (`comicDetails.info`) as well.

Comment: I think you can tell the `fetch` which attributes you want to retrieve. Can't see you get much benefit from having two objects though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to have two entities is to get the behavior you're hoping for. In general when you do a Core Data fetch, only instances of the entity type you request are loaded into memory. Related objects are not immediately loaded. Instead, Core Data loads them automatically on demand.

In your case, if you fetch `ComicInfos`, only `ComicInfos` get loaded. But if you take one of those objects and access its `details` attribute, the related `ComicDetails` instance is automatically loaded, without needing to do another fetch. The related objects are only loaded when you ask for them. So, you're getting the behavior you want.

If you ever want to override this behavior, you can use `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:` to force `NSFetchRequest` to load not only the objects you actually fetch, but also specific related objects as well.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that possibly this is what was happening, but wasn't sure.